# How can I dynamically add or remove validation

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently trying to create a dynamic form with Angularjs. For testing purposes the form has 3 fields that are added dynamically over a ng-repeat directive.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charms/4E7zQ/3/

**Question:**

I currently try to dynamically set validation directives. I would like to achive following:

```
<input ng-model="item.value" name="{{item.name}}" type="{{item.type}}" placeholder="{{item.placeholder}}" {{item.validators}}/>
```

**{{item.validators}}** however doesn't work. Does anybody know how I can add and remove basic and custom validators during dynamic field creation?

I would like to add different validators to the dynamically added form fields and also remove the validators if the fields are removed:

```
<input ng-model="user.email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required email-available/>
<input ng-model="user.firstName" name="firstName" type="email" placeholder="Firstname" required/>
<input ng-model="user.lastName" name="lastName" type="email" placeholder="Lastname" required"/>
```

Is this possible with Angularjs?

For example the fields and validations should change depending on to which radio button the user is clicking. I want to achieve this by removing the field and add it again with different validation directives dynamically added to it.

As you can see in the JSFiddle when clicking on to the "Add" button 3 fields will be created with a "required" directive. If one form field is removed (which is achieved by clicking on to the remove button), also the validation is removed.

Now I would like to add another field with a different validation directive such as email-available for example or multiple validation directives which are each different for each of the fields that are created.

It would be great if somebody has a solution for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the page on custom validation http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms. All the validation happens in the ngModel controller. There are two arrays which hold sanitizers and validators - [$formatters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#%24formatters) and [$parsers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#%24parsers). What I would do is write a directive that takes a list of validators as a parameter and adds or removes them to and from the lists I mentioned above.

The only problem I see is with reusing the built-in validators. Perhaps you could pluck the validator functions from the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js) and put in your directive. It is not very pretty, but not hard.

Or you could just write the validators yourself. Each one of them is just a regex. Here's how my team has been doing it:

```
.value('validators', (function () {
    function validatorFromRegex(regex) {
        return function (value) {
            return (!value) ? true : (value.toString().match(regex) !== null);
        };
    }
    return {
        required: function (value) { return (value !== ''); },
        path: validatorFromRegex(/^\/?([0-9A-Za-z]+[\-\/]?)*[0-9A-Za-z]+$/),
        tag: validatorFromRegex(/^([0-9A-Za-z]+\-?)*[0-9A-Za-z]+$/),
        date: validatorFromRegex(/^(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)\d\d$/),
        spotify: validatorFromRegex(/^spotify:user:fusetv:playlist:[a-zA-Z0-9]{22}$/),
        url: validatorFromRegex(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/),
        twitter: validatorFromRegex(/^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$/),
        number: validatorFromRegex(/^\d+$/),
        phone: validatorFromRegex(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/),
        zipcode: validatorFromRegex(/^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/)
    };
})())
```

Comment: hi Ivan, thanks for your reply. is the code snipped that you posted a part of the directive? I'll have a look at the $formatters and $parsers. I thought that Angularjs maybe supports something out of the box. But you're right. This doesn't seem to be the case and your solution looks good.

Comment: Well, it is just a static object that contains a bunch of validators, but can be used in a directive.